# Can all vectors be expressed as the product of a symmetric matrix with non-zero off-diagonal elements and the vector of ones?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, symmetric-matrices

\begin{equation}
\forall \ (\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n) \ \exists \ (A \in \mathbb{A}) \ : \ A \mathbf{1} = \mathbf{x}
\end{equation}

Hi, I'm writing a paper about certain difference equations on undirected graphs. I'm trying to prove that any steady-state solution is possible on the complete graph. Here $\mathbb{A}$ is the set of symmetric matrices which have non-zero off-diagonal elements (all weighted adjacency matrices for the complete graph), and $\mathbf{1} $ is the vector of ones.

I'm an undergraduate, and I don't have a clue as to where to start with this. Is is trivially true because we always have more elements of $A$ than equations to solve them with? If not, what are the possible $\mathbf{x}$? Which $A$ satisfy $A \mathbf{1}=\mathbf{x}$ for a given $\mathbf{x}$, and is there an algorithm for finding the elements of $A$?

Update: I think I've made some headway, but not much. For the $2 \times 2$ case the following holds:

\begin{bmatrix}
c_1 x_1+c_2 x_2 & (1-c_1)x_1-c_2 x_2\\
(1-c_1)x_1-c_2 x_2 & -(1-c_1)x_1 + (1+c_2)x_2\\
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: As there are more equations than variables if we want to find some $A$, we can simply try. One way would be to express $A=D+B$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix and $B$ is a matrix all elements of which are identical.If $x$ is positive and you want a positive $A$, then choose a small positive $B$ and it will work out.

Comment: Do you want the off diagonals being positive?

Comment: @user251257 Yes, and it's nice to know that they don't have to be. Positive weights are the only way to guarantee that the update matrix doesn't have any eigenvalues equal to $-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\ b\ $ be any non-zero number, $\ a_i= x_i-(n-1)b\ $ for all $i$, and
$$
A =\pmatrix{a_1&b&b&\dots&b&b\\
             b & a_2& b&\dots&b&b\\
             b & b& a_3 &\dots &b&b\\
           \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
              b&b&b&\dots&a_{n-1}& b\\
             b&b&b&\dots&b& a_n  }\ .
$$

Answer (score 1):

Define $A_{ij} = x_i / n$. Would that suffice?

EDIT: duh, this is not symmetric. See lonza's answer instead.

Comment: This is not symmetric.